# React Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I made a form with Formik and react-reaflet, when the user clicks on the button, a map appears with a predefined longitude and latitude and he can navigate on the map and automatically change its location by dragging the cursor.

The functionality works as expected but when I click on the cursor to change the location, React shows me in the console this error **Warning: Cannot update a component (`Main`) while rendering a different component (`Formik`).**. I tried to solve it but it still doesn't work. I created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lfv2u) so you can see how the error appears on the console

Comment: the link is now dead, so we can no longer see the context for the answer. Can you edit (some of) the code into your question?

Comment: @Pureferret  https://codesandbox.io/s/lfv2u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `components/mapper.js` ln:12.

You did:

```
setLatitude(latitude);
setLongitude(longitude);
```

right inside a rendering function. Why do you do that?

Comment: I did that because I thought that  i could use it as a state in the parent component

Comment: It's just not necessary.

Comment: thank you so much, i delete that and now it's working without errors

Answer (score 0):

Just to generalize what @hackape said, when using functional components, don't use `setState` plainly on a component's body (you need to initialize the state on definitions or wrap it with `useEffect`/other callable functions)

Example:

```js
function MyComponent(props){
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)

  setState(5) // This is BAD

  return <View />
}
```

Solutions:

```js
function MyComponent(props){
  const [state, setState] = useState(5) // This is good

  return <View />
}

// -------- OR ---------
function MyComponent(props){
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)

  useEffect(()=>{
    setState(5) // This is good
  },[])

  return <View />
}
```